# Count the O's from a Given String, say="*XOO*O"

Tags: java

If a 'O' is placed adjacent to an 'X', an 'O' always gets killed. But if a '*' comes infront of 'X', it gets out of options. So ,out of a Given Combination, find the num.of O's alive.

I had this program. but it will fail certain Test Cases like
String str="*OOXOO*OO". o/p should be two. but mine would give 4.

Here is my code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter Test Cases ");
        String test = br.readLine();

        int t = Integer.parseInt(test);

        if (t >= 1 && t <= 30) {
            for (int loop = 0; loop < t; loop++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Input String ");
                String inp = br.readLine();
                inp = "." + inp + ".";
                StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(inp);
                int k = inp.length();
                int count = 0;
                if (k >= 1 && k <= 100000) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                        char ch = inp.charAt(i);
                        if (ch == 'O') {
                            if (!((inp.charAt(i + 1)) == 'X' || (inp
                                    .charAt(i - 1)) == 'X')) {
                                //strb.deleteCharAt(i);
                                count++;

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Total TestClass Alive is  " + count);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "out of options"?

Comment: It looks like the answer is 4 in your example. Maybe explain more clearly the conditions?

Comment: Ah the semester in the US has started again, hasn't it?

Comment: What do you see when you debug you code in a debugger. Why not use a couple of replaceAll()

Comment: @Voo Yes, but the asker doesn't seem American.

Comment: @Makoto it seems that as long as `X` has `O's` adjacent it deletes them. But when it reaches `*` it stops. So my guess is that the example would result in something like `*X*OO` - and that is 2 `O's`. But that's only a guess ;)

Comment: @Voo , Buddy let me make that very Clear. I am new to programming, n this isnt some kind of Sem.Questions!! I am jus trying to get an Idea!

Comment: @MichałSchielmann Yeah, absolutely right!!

Comment: @chrylis  Not American. U got that Right,sweet!

Comment: @user3280711 In that case I can post an answer, please see if it's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is this check:

```
if (ch == 'O') {
    if (!((inp.charAt(i + 1)) == 'X' || (inp.charAt(i - 1)) == 'X')) {
        count++
    }
}
```

Here you check for only a case where there is O not surrounded by X. But this check doesn't work for cases like *OOXOO*. You'll get 2 but the result is 0. So the solution is to do it in loop or using regexp. Examples are shown below.

Also you did that:

```
inp = "." + inp + ".";
```

which I think is not needed. I'm guessing you did that because you were getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while looping for `i = 0`. The solution you proposed works, but you could also add check in the loop for `(i>0)` or start from 1 and check behind + front (see examples below).

If you don't require a loop with array then you can use a simple regex:

```
testString = testString.replaceAll("[O]+X","X").replaceAll("X[O]+", "X");
```

The whole test-program:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Test String: ");
        String testString = br.readLine();
        testString = "." + testString + ".";

        testString = testString.replaceAll("[O]+X","X").replaceAll("X[O]+", "X");

        int count = testString.length() - testString.replace("O", "").length();
        System.out.println("Result string:  " + testString);
        System.out.println("Total 'O' left:  " + count);
    }
}
```

**Test1:**

```
Enter Test String: *OOX*XOX*OO*XO*O*X*OX*XO*O*
Result string:  .*X*XX*OO*X*O*X*X*X*O*.
Total 'O' left:  4
```

**Test2:**

```
Enter Test String: *OOXOO*OO
Result string:  .*X*OO.
Total 'O' left:  2
```

**Test3:**

```
Enter Test String: *O*OXOO*OO
Result string:  .*O*X*OO.
Total 'O' left:  3
```

**EDIT**
Below there are 3 types of solutions to your problem:

```
public class Main {

    private BufferedReader userInput;
    private String testString;

    public static void main(final String args[])
    {
        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  //get the reader.
        Main test = new Main(userInput); //create an object of a test class that will use this reader
        test.getTestString(); //ask user for the input
        test.removeOsWithRegex();  //first method - regex
        test.removeOsByReplacingWithX(); //second method - in loop change all O's to X's
        test.removeOsByInLoopDeletion(); //third method - delete all O's step by step in a loop.
    }

    public Main(final BufferedReader userInput)
    {
        this.userInput = userInput;  //constructor
    }

    //getting the test string.
    private void getTestString()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Test String: ");
        try
        {
            testString = userInput.readLine();
            testString = "." + testString + ".";
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something wrong happened: " + e.getMessage() + ". Shutting down.");
        }
    }

    //removing with regex
    private void removeOsWithRegex()
    {
        System.out.println("Removing 'O' with regexp from: " + testString);

        //change all parts of testString where there are Os followed by X to X.
        //do the same with parts of testString where there is X followed by one or more O.
        String resultString = testString.replaceAll("[O]+X","X").replaceAll("X[O]+", "X");
        //the number of Os is the length of the string minus length of the string without Os.
        int count = resultString.length() - resultString.replace("O", "").length();
        System.out.println("Result string:  " + resultString);
        System.out.println("Total 'O' left:  " + count);
    }

    //2nd method
    public void removeOsByReplacingWithX()
    {
        System.out.println("Removing 'O' by replacing them with X: " + testString);

        byte[] byteArray = testString.getBytes();
        boolean changesMade;
        //create loop
        do
        {
            changesMade = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < byteArray.length - 1; i++)
            {
                //if X was found change adjacent Os to X
                if (byteArray[i] == 'X')
                {
                    if (byteArray[i-1] == 'O')
                    {
                        byteArray[i-1] = 'X';
                        changesMade = true;
                    }
                    if (byteArray[i+1] == 'O')
                    {
                        byteArray[i+1] = 'X';
                        changesMade = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(changesMade);  //do this as long as there is something to change.

        String resultString = new String(byteArray);

        int count = resultString.length() - resultString.replace("O", "").length();
        System.out.println("Result string:  " + resultString);
        System.out.println("Total 'O' left:  " + count);
    }


    //3rd method
    public void removeOsByInLoopDeletion()
    {
        System.out.println("Removing 'O' by deleting them in loop: " + testString);

        byte[] byteArray = testString.getBytes();
        boolean changesMade;
        //create a loop
        do
        {
            changesMade = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < byteArray.length - 1; i++)
            {
                //if there is X
                if (byteArray[i] == 'X')
                {
                    //if next is O then shorten the array by cutting the O
                    if (byteArray[i+1] == 'O')
                    {
                        byteArray = shortenByteArray(byteArray, i+1); //i+1 is the position of O
                        changesMade = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //on the other hand if O was wound
                if (byteArray[i] == 'O')
                {
                    //if X is next, shorten it by cutting O from current position
                    if (byteArray[i+1] == 'X')
                    {
                        byteArray = shortenByteArray(byteArray, i); //i is current position.
                        changesMade = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(changesMade);

        String resultString = new String(byteArray);

        int count = resultString.length() - resultString.replace("O", "").length();
        System.out.println("Result string:  " + resultString);
        System.out.println("Total 'O' left:  " + count);
    }

    //cutting one element from byte array
    private byte[] shortenByteArray(final byte[] byteArray, final Integer startIndex)
    {
        byte[] newByteArray = new byte[byteArray.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < newByteArray.length; i++)
        {
            //rewrite all before the item to cut
            if (i < startIndex)
            {
                newByteArray[i] = byteArray[i];
            }
            else
            {
                //ommit the element to cut and move all others by 1.
                newByteArray[i] = byteArray[i+1];
            }
        }
        return newByteArray;
    }
}
```

The results are the same for all three cases for all 3 tests I've supplied earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote on the well commented code and explanation of the OP problem :) Good day :)

Comment: Schielmann Well, thanks for such a detailed Explnation! But i dont think, i have actualy downvoted ur answer!!

Comment: @user3280711 im not suggesting it's you :) No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It should work if I understood your question.

```
private static String removeO(final char[] str) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
        switch (str[index]) {
        case 'X':
            if (index != 0) {
                int aIndex = index;
                while (aIndex != 0 && str[--aIndex] == 'O') {
                    buff.deleteCharAt(buff.length() - 1);
                }
                buff.append(str[index]);
                aIndex = index;
                while (aIndex != str.length - 1 && str[++aIndex] == 'O') {
                    index++;
                }
            } else if (index != 0) {
                buff.append(str[index]);
            }

            break;
        default:
            buff.append(str[index]);
            break;
        }
    }

    return buff.toString();
}

private static int countO(final char[] str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (final char ch : str) {
        if (ch == 'O') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final char[] str1 = "*OOXOO*OO".toCharArray();

    System.out.println(countO(removeO(str1).toCharArray()));

    final char[] str2 = "*O*OXOO*OO".toCharArray();

    System.out.println(countO(removeO(str2).toCharArray()));
}
```

Comment: Can you share the test case? I can take a look.

Comment: "*O*OXOO*OO"-o/p-shuld be 3, coming 4

Comment: Fine. I understood the problem in a different way. Now I have modified the code to remove all the adjacent Os. Please try this.

Comment: @Loganathan Mohanraj: Presumably someone downvoting to discourage people from answering "give me the code" questions with exactly that.

Comment: @Loganathan Mohanraj - it's probably as Voo said. I've got one too, even after posting an answer to already solved question.
Well, what can we do... its -2 for us, -1 for the downvoter.

Comment: I guess so but generally is it not advisable to post the code in stackoverflow?

Comment: On the contrary, it is advisable to post the code. But this question was not very clear and the OP did not write what the problem was exactly. In answers you should explain what the problem was and what changes are needed for the code to start working, including code itself. But probably you shouldn't write the whole solution, because that's OP job to do that. But in that case it's really a simple function, so I wouldn't be so strict.

Comment: Plus it was not the worst question I've seen here. The OP supplied his code and wrote that it doesn't work for some cases. So i don't really get the downvoter, especially that he/she didn't want to explain his reasons... Now that's a bad SO practice. But hey! Who am I to judge;)

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
int ocount = input.replaceAll("[*]X", "O").replaceAll("XO", "").split ("O").length - 1;
```

To debug you code, I suggest using you debugger to step through what it is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String output = new String();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        String strArr[] = br.readLine().split("\\*");
        int enemy=0;
        for(String str:strArr){
            if(str.contains("X")){
                continue;
            }
            if(count('X',str)==0){
                enemy=enemy+str.length();
            }
        }
        output=output+enemy+"\n";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}

private static int count(char c,String str){
    int count=0;
    char charArr[] = str.toCharArray();
    for(char c2:charArr){
        if(c==c2){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry i dont know what exaactly is u taking as Input